Display icon on screen
I want to create an application or library to display icons like "back" and "forward" on the middle of the left and right edges of the screen, similar to how Chrome shows navigation icons when swiped with two fingers. What libraries or tools can I use for this, and how should I approach the development? I’ve tried using feh, but it lacks the customization I need.
